# How to automate my if statement to write two excel documents in openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

In my code I am converting a csv file into pandas then I am adjusting the data in the columns

```
df = df[['Lastname', 'Firstname','Company','Title','Willing_to_share','Willing_to_introduce','work_phones','Work_email','Work_Street','Work_City','Work_State','Work_Zip','Personal_Street','Personal_City','Personal_State','Personal_Zip','mobile_phones','Personal_email','Note','Note_Category']]
##print(df)
## Lastname Firstname          Company Title Willing_to_share  \
0       Doe      Jane                                           
1   Malcoun       Joe  8/28/2019 14:29                          
2   Ramirez    Morgan                                           
3     Burki     Roman                                           
4      None    Jordan                                           
5      None                                                     
6  Zachuani     Reemo                                           
7    Suarez   Geraldo     
 Willing_to_introduce work_phones              Work_email  \
0                       5678743546        j@greenbriar.com   
1                             None        ceo@nutshell.com   
2                       3338765438      mramirez@nerdy.com   
3                       5468756098           burki@bvb.com   
4                             None  jordanw45490@gmail.com   
5                             None                   ronny   
6                             None                           
7                             None   

              Work_Street      Work_City Work_State Work_Zip Personal_Street  \
0        54 George street  Ridge Springs         VA    25678                   
1     212 South Fifth Ave      Ann Arbor         MI    48103                   
2              567 one st     Birmingham         AL    45678                   
3  546 fourteen street Nw         Dallas         TX    54678                   
4                                                                              
5                                                                              
6                                                                              
7       456 yellow street                                                      

  Personal_City Personal_State Personal_Zip mobile_phones Personal_email Note  \
0                                              3245687907                       
1                                                    None                       
2                                              6780431874                       
3                                              0983457690                       
4                                                    None                       
5                                                    None                       
6                                                    None                       
7                                                    None                       

  Note_Category  
0                
1                
2                
3                
4                
5                
6                
7
```

I have created the workbooks before the if statement

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
wb.title = 'Contacts'
wb2 = Workbook()
ws2 = wb2.active
wb2.title = 'Contacts'
```

I have two issues in my code the first issue is I have tried a number of solutions but I cannot add the dataframe data in the excel sheet properly according to the if statement. The if statement sets conditions to add the pandas data rows to the accepted contacts otherwise the rows not passing the condition should be added to the rejected contacts workbooks. What am I getting is in the accepting contacts the full contacts are looped in the workbook and are added once into the rejected contacts

```
for column, row in df.iterrows():
  row_check = row.isna()
  if (not row_check[0] and not row_check[1]) and ((not row_check[2] and not row_check[3]) or (not row_check[2]) and (not row_check[6]) or (not row_check[16]) and (not row_check[12] and not row_check[13] and not row_check[14] and row_check[15]) or (not row_check[8] and not row_check[9] and not row_check[10] and not row_check[11] and (not row_check[7] or not row_check[17]))):
       for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
           ws.append(r)
else:
       for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
           ws2.append(r)

wb.save("Accepted Contacts.xlsx")
wb2.save("Rejected Contacts.xlsx")
```

The second issue is adding borders to each excel sheet automatically according to the length of the pandas dataframe. Right now I do it manually inside both the if and else statements.

```
       A3 = ws['A3'] 
       A3.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)
       A3.alignment=Alignment(horizontal='general',
         vertical='bottom',
         text_rotation=0,
         wrap_text=True,
         shrink_to_fit=False,
         indent=0)
...
       T6 = ws['T6'] 
       T6.border = Border(top=thin, left=thin, right=thin, bottom=thin)
       T6.alignment=Alignment(horizontal='general',
         vertical='bottom',
         text_rotation=0,
         wrap_text=True,
         shrink_to_fit=False,
         indent=0)
```

[image: Accepted Worksheet currently]
[image: Rejected Worksheet currently]

Comment: What should the if statement check? And what's the issue with the borders?

Comment: The if statement should check if each row in the dataframe has certain cells which are null or not. Based on this condition if a row passes the if statement it should be added to the excel accepted workbook otherwise the row would be added to the rejected contacts workbook.

Comment: As for the borders I want the border to only be the length of the data in each workbook

Comment: One possibility with the if statement is that you could add another column `to_excel` and set that before writing the Excel file with your current if statement. When writing the Excel file you only look at that column to decide.

Comment: About the borders, doesn't the row in Pandas tell you how long it is? Then you can use the functions stated [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html) or something like `ws.cell(row=4, column=2).border ...`